# How to apply utf-8 to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, utf-8, amazon-rds

I'm using RDS on ElasticbeansTalk of AWS.
As I noticed Japanese character on RDS, I tried to change settings on RDS parameter group like this.
[image: RDS]

And this

[image]

Even though I modified some settings, the configuration didn't still work.

No matter what I import csv data including Japanese character, the table is getting like this.

[image: MySQL table data]

How should I do? Could you tell me how to apply utf-8 on existing RDS(EB) tables?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

I figured out by myself.
All I have to do is to apply some SQL.

`ALTER TABLE (table name) CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8`

Sorry for bothering.